# setVisible property called before any drawing is made

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I am trying to build a game in Swing, I know I could use other tools, but this is just for learning purposes. The problem I am facing is related to threads.

Basically the Main Thread runs the setVisible property of the JFrame (Window class) before any drawing is done to the JPanel (GamePanel class). After I've done some research I have found that I could solve this problem using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` method, which is supposed to give some time to the game thread to prepare the drawings made on the JPanel.

I have also tried to place the `setVisible (true)` property in a different thread and made that thread sleep for 2, 3 seconds. Both of these methods work sometimes and sometimes don't.

I don't know if this makes a difference but my operating system is: macOS Catalina.

Trivial example which causes this thread problem.

**GameLauncher**

```
public class GameLauncher {

public GameLauncher(){
    new Window("MyGame");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new GameLauncher();
}

}
```

**Window**

```
public class Window extends JFrame {

    public Window(String title){
        setTitle(title);

        setContentPane(new GamePanel(1280, 1280));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
//        setVisible(true);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->setVisible(true));
    }
}
```

**GamePanel**

```
package com.progresso.games;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable {

public int width;
public int height;

private BufferedImage bufferedImage;

private Thread gameThread;
private boolean isRunning = false;

Graphics2D graphics2D = null;

public GamePanel(int width, int height){
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    setFocusable(true);
    requestFocus();
}

@Override
public void addNotify() {
    super.addNotify();
    if(gameThread == null){
        gameThread = new Thread(this, "GameThread");
        gameThread.start();
    }
}

private void init(){
    isRunning = true;

    bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    graphics2D = (Graphics2D) bufferedImage.getGraphics();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    init();

    while (isRunning) {
        update();
        render(graphics2D);
        draw();
    }

}

private void update(){ }

private void render(Graphics2D g){
    if(g != null){
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0,0, width, height);
    }
}

private void draw(){ }

}
```

Comment: Generally speaking, this is a known issue.  Until the component is realised on the screen (ie, attached to a native peer and sized), no painting is done.  There's not a lot you can do in this case.  One solution "might be" to place the window off screen, allow enough time for it to do at least one render path and then move it back to the main screen ... seems like a lot of effort personally

Comment: Some notes. Swing is not thread safe.  This means that you shouldn't try to update the UI or something the UI depends on from outside the context of the event dispatching thread.  Swing is also already double buffered.  A simpler solution would be to use a Swing `Timer` (instead of a `Thread`) and simply update the state and then allow `paintComponent` to render that state on the next paint pass

Comment: Could you leave a trivial example using the `Timer` ?

Comment: [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34843331/make-circles-randomly-dis-appear-change-color-using-swing-timer/34844620#34844620), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22748547/java-swing-timer-only-works-once-then-keyevents-fire-in-rapid-succession-holdi/22749251#22749251)

Comment: You should also have a look at [How to use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Answer (score 1):

It is rarely a good idea to subclass a JFrame. Extend a JPanel instead, and paint your stuff in its paintCpomponent() method. Try something like this (incomplete code):

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel {

   public GamePanel() {
      // Create panel content here
   }

   @Override
   public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      g.fillRect(0,0, width, height);
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

         @Override
         public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            // create the component to display in the frame
            JPanel panel = new GamePanel();
            ;
            frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
               @Override
               public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) {
                  System.exit(0);
               }
            });
         }

      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Good advice, unlikely to fix the problem though

Comment: I've used the render method because in my case I will have multiple states of the game, and every state and game object (like player, enemies) will have a render method which does sth to the JPanel, that's why I haven't used `paintComponent(...)`.

Comment: Isn't there a method that can push the set visible property after we're done with the drawing :?

Comment: Your gamePane class should have an instance variable that contains a list of all of the game objects. The objects should have a render(g) method, and gamePanel's paintComponent method cycles through each of the objects calling their render method.

Comment: @user181475 *"will have a render method which does sth to the JPanel, that's why I haven't used paintComponent(...)"* - This isn't how painting works.  Swing will call the `paintComponent` when it wants something rendered, so you have no choice but to use it. `setIgnoreRepaint` seem naive to me. If you really want control over the paint process then you should be use a `java.awt.Canvas` and use a `BufferStrategy` instead